# http.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader() caused deadlock

Tags: http, testing, go

I was trying to use the `httptest` package in golang. I found out something I don't understand. Here is the [code](https://play.golang.org/p/-hDoay9lq0z):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello1"))
    }))
    ts.Close()
    ts = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello2"))
    }))
    ts.Close()
    ts = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(100)
        w.Write([]byte("Hello3"))
    }))

    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    greeting, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ts.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%s", greeting)
}
```

In this code example, I was trying to open and close `httptest` servers several times. Somehow it caused deadlock in The Go Playground. I tried on my own environment (Go version: go1.7.4 darwin/amd64) and it caused hanging without responding at all.

My question is: Why `w.WriteHeader(100)` caused deadlock but `w.WriteHeader(200)` doesn't? Is it the bug from the core library of Golang or just I misunderstood some usage? Tks!

Comment: Possibly `100 Continue` reply code supposes some actions further so library is awaiting for next steps.

Comment: Why are you sending `100`? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Go doesn't seem to send the 100 (StatusContinue) response to the client. If you reorder it so that you write Hello3 first then it'll finally send a successful response (check out https://play.golang.org/p/gX1ra-xFSA8 - doesn't work on playground, but it'll on your system), and try playing around with it. And yes, what do you want to do btw ?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Doesn't `Close()` mean that it should shut down the server anyhow?

Comment: @Flimzy I was just trying some `httptest` code and found that. I was confused if it's consider a bug.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What did you expect would happen? What is your reason for using 100? Was it just "to see what happens"? If so, now you know what happens.

Comment: @chyeh it cannot get to it - please look my answer.

Comment: @Ravi thanks for your example! I'm wondering if it's because 100 causes the server to wait for the following requests from the client. And I was just playing the `httptest` package!

Comment: @Flimzy I read the [document](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=2857:5217#L81) again and I guest I understand now. It just behaves this way.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Thanks! I just understood. After `w.WriteHeader(100)` is called it waits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you slightly modify code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello1"))
    }))
    ts.Close()
    ts = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello2"))
    }))
    ts.Close()
    ts = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(100)
        w.Write([]byte("Hello3"))
    }))

    fmt.Println("before get")   ///// . <----
    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
    fmt.Println("after get")    ///// . <----
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    greeting, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ts.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%s", greeting)
}
```

and run it - you'll see only first line.

That means Go http client want more data from you. So it hangs on line

```
    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
```

and cannot get to the `ts.Close()` below.

Next - lets modify a test, so it will close a connection and this way release a clients waiting lock:

```
ts = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(100)
    w.Write([]byte("Hello3"))
    hj, _ := w.(http.Hijacker)
    conn, _, _ := hj.Hijack()
    conn.Close()
}))
```

I close connection explicitly  but this way you get both check strings and test finishes ok. Try it.

Of course it's a HTTP protocol violation so I get an error:

```
Get http://127.0.0.1:54243: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: unexpected EOF
```

Comment: Well, I wonder if we can call it a bug that Go never communicates the Continue Status to the client as it probably should as per the RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.2.1). One may assume not too many applications make use of this?